# Neural network with same result for every test

Tags: python, neural-network, image-recognition

I want to train a neural network with these information:

```
input : a logical image   -> 115*115 + 1 nodes   #+1 for bias
output: detected alphabet -> 24 nodes
hidden: i think           -> 6 nodes
activation function       -> tanh()
```

At the begin, I initialize weights with random numbers between [-1, 1]. 
After training the NN, I got same results for every sample.

*I found the problem:* Because of many inputs, at the first layer numbers are huge and when I apply tanh() on them, outputs are 1, -1 only.

I tested these 2 solution but couldn't help me:

- Scale weights to [-0.1, 0.1]
- Expand tanh(x) function to tanh(x/N) with N=1000, 10000
- Scale the input datas from [0, 1] to [-1, 1]

Any tips or your experience may be useful :)

---

### Extra:

I want to used my own code, and for test I used this function (same as Activate( ) function):

```
def test(self,Inp):
    Inp = np.reshape(Inp,(self.m,self.i))
    A1 = Inp.dot(self.W1.transpose())
    Z1 = np.tanh(A1) 
    A2 = Z1.dot(self.W2.transpose())
    Y = np.tanh(A2)
    return Y
```

Consider we have random weights, Why output of test function is the same always ?

Comment: Library used? Relevant parts of code?

Comment: I added main part the of code. W1, W2 are numpy arrays.

Comment: Sure you don't use the same seed in each run for the random number generation?

Comment: I'm generating random numbers once, in __init __ function and just for weights. Then I updating weights and use real images for inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I have many inputs and I must decrease them. 
So I use `PCA` to convert 115*115 to 200 features and the problem was solved!